# Does tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() support GRPC?

Tags: python, session, tensorflow, distributed, grpc

We need to define multiple clients (each creates and builds Tensorflow Session/graph) using "Between-graph Replication" in Distributed Tensorflow. Typically, the client and worker are in the same process, and `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession()` coordinates those Tensorflow Sessions.

Now if each client and worker is not in the same process, and I want client to use grpc to remotely drive worker tasks, I wonder if `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession()` or some APIs support this feature, or if anyone has any other solutions or ideas. (I know `tf.Session(<grpc_url>)` supports grpc, but it does not coordinate multiple Tensorflow Sessions)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredTrainingSession) can use gRPC. However, you must create the [`tf.train.Server`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Server) object manually (typically one per process), as shown in the [Distributed TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).

Once you have created a `tf.train.Server`, the most common way to configure a `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` for distributed training is to call `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target)`, where `server` is one of the servers in the `"worker"` job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But still seems not clear to me. Basically, I imagine `MonitoredTrainingSession` appears in client side as it creates and starts a tf session. As I'm using grpc with "Between-graph Replication", and each client is a separate process for worker, I wonder how worker and client code look like (I imagine worker creates server object. But as `MonitoredTrainingSession` appears in client process which uses that obj, does it mean I need create another same server obj in client?) Also, how does `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` tell if the session is running with grpc or not?